# Can't type UTF-8 chars in PhpStorm

Tags: utf-8, phpstorm, archlinux, kde-plasma

Ok so wierd thing is happening to me in phpStorm, every time I try to type a utf-8 char like 'é' in phpStorm it just shows up as '�', both the global encoding settings and the project are set to UTF-8, the wierd thing is that it can display them if I simply paste them, but when I try to type it it just shows up as that.

I also tried setting "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to the vmoptions but that doesn't work either.

Currently using Arch Linux with kernel 4.11.6-3, with KDE plasma 5, not sure if that might have to do anything with it but just to make sure I'm saying it.

Comment: Has it always been this way in PhpStorm? Please restart it, type such a character in and then upload the IDE log somewhere - maybe something comes up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to solve a problem that I didn't see as related I ended up fixing this so here goes the solution:

I went in /etc/locale.conf and checked if en_US.UTF-8 was commented, which it was for some reason, so I uncommented it, ran (sudo) locale-gen and the next time I ran phpstorm I saw that it was solved.

In ubuntu if I'm not mistaken if you have the same problem you can do something like this in /etc/default/locales, but you will have to check how to generate locales for that.

Arch: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale 
Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale